# How do i include Rails join table field in the form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In this scenario I can insert values to the Member table and the Club table. But there is a field called `:task` in the `memberships` table that I want to submit a value to, and in the Memberships table `member_id` and `club_id` are inserted automatically by Rails. How do I include the `task` field in the form below? Thank you in advance.

View/form:

```
<%= form_for @member ,:url=>{:action =>"create"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.fields_for :clubs do |s| %>
    <%= s.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Models

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clubs ,:through=> :memberships
  has_many :memberships
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :clubs 
  attr_accessible :clubs_attributes
end

class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members ,:through=>:memberships
  has_many :memberships
end

class Memberships < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Member
  belongs_to :Club
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%= f.fields_for :memberships do |m| %>
  <%= m.text_field :task %>
  <%= m.fields_for :clubs do |s| %>
    <%= s.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you @DGM what would be added in the controllers to make this possible?