# How to get a nested text_area to render properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have a scaffold called submits that has a form for creating new submissions. I also created a model called question. I've used this model to create different questions in the submission form.I've utilized a join form and use active admin to add/edit questions from the backend. I'm getting this error.

```
undefined method `submit[question_ids][]' for #<Submit id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

submits.rb

```
class Submit < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :questions
end
```

question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :submits
end
```

subits/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@submit) do |f| %>
 <% if @submit.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">
     <h2><%= pluralize(@submit.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this submit from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @submit.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name,"Team Name" %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control"  %>
</div>

<% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label(question.question)%>
    <%= f.text_area "submit[question_ids][]" %>
  </div>
<% end %> 

  <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit "Apply", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm guessing my error is here:

```
 <%= f.text_area "submit[question_ids][]" %>
```

I'm just not sure what the correct syntax is. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Rails form_for input forms, you need `:(whatever attribute)` which should be defined in your migration file.

ex.) if you have 'text' attribute in your Submit model you can have your input form for the text attribute just like this. `<%= f.text_area :text %>`

But in this case it seems like you have a join table for your models, so I think you should `fields_for` for your join table.

cf.) [How do i include Rails join table field in the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326551/how-do-i-include-rails-join-table-field-in-the-form)

Comment: Thank you! Took me a couple days to get back to this problem. Your answer was spot on the link really helped. I appreciate it.